# EngineIoClientDotNet change path

Tags: c#, node.js, xamarin, socket.io, maui

I'm using `Node.js` with `socket.io` server and `EngineIoClientDotNet` and `MAUI` on client side. This is how I'm connecting to the server on client side using `Quobject.EngineIoClientDotNet.Client.Socket`:

```
socket = new Socket("https://api.example.com");
```

And here's how it is on server side:

```
const io: Server = new Server(server, { cors: { origin: "*" } });
```

And instead of making requests to `https://api.example.com/socket.io`, like `socket.io-client` for javascript, `EngineIoClientDotNet` makes requests to `https://api.example.com/engine.io`, which resultst in 404 response.

**How do I change path from `/engine.io` to `/socket.io`?**

Comment: which specific client are you using?  Every one I can find has been deprecated

Comment: @Jason, This one: [EngineIoClientDotNet](https://github.com/Quobject/EngineIoClientDotNet)

Comment: https://github.com/Quobject/EngineIoClientDotNet/issues/69

Answer (score 0):

**Use SocketIOClient** 
`EngineIoClientDotNet` is deprecated, and `SocketIOClient` is still maintained.
If you need to change path from `/socket.io` (which is default in `SocketIOClient`) use `SocketIOOptions`:

```
using SocketIOClient;


socket = new SocketIO("https://example.com", new SocketIOOptions() { Path = "/custom-path" });
```

[NuGet SocketIOClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SocketIOClient) 
[Github SocketIOClient](https://github.com/doghappy/socket.io-client-csharp)